Negative numbers in Binary Search Function
I have created a binary search function operating in a divide and conquer fashion.
Comparing the middle index value of an array, for smaller or larger to the sought value.
If the middle index is higher than then sought value than we look for the middle index between that midpoint and the leftIndex (initialized as 0), and the opposite for the right side.
Very simple and everything works fine, my question is that when. a testcase is introduced with negative number, for example, [-1,0,3,5,9,12] and searching for 9, we get a timeout and it cannot compute.
My array is sorted, so I am curious to know why this would not work, considering the integer values are compareable, and that looking for the value of 9, the -1 at index 0 would not even be considered, in this particular example.
Please see my function here.
function binarySearch(arr, val){
    //lets first declare our left and right values 
    let leftIdx = 0;
    let rightIdx = arr.length - 1
  
    while(leftIdx <= rightIdx){
    //while left idx is smaller or equal to right
    //lets calculate the middle
    let middleIndex = Math.floor(leftIdx + rightIdx / 2);
    //lets extract the value from this middleIndex
    let middleVal = arr[middleIndex]
    
    if(val < middleVal){
      //if our sought value is smaller than the middle
      rightIdx = middleIndex - 1
    } else if(val > middleVal){
      //if our sought value is bigger than middle
      leftIdx = middleIndex + 1
    
    } else {
      return middleIndex
    }
  }
  return -1
}


Have you tried debugging to verify that the index values are what you expect them to be?

and everything works fine - assuming it's meant to return the index, you might want to try a few more test cases, eg binarySearch([1,2,3], 3) => 3.   should be 2, there's no [3] index.

middleVal can sometimes be undefined.  When you do greater than/less than comparisons with undefined you get these results, in this case your code is falling into the else block.

Add an escape clause, eg let escape = 0; while () { if (escape++>arr.length) return -2; at least, while debugging

The negative number is a red-herring.  It's just that's the first one you found where it doesn't work - you need a lot more test cases, eg binarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 7)

Remember your operator precedence rules (BODMAS / BIDMAS) when calculating values.

You forgot parentheses:
 let middleIndex = Math.floor((leftIdx + rightIdx) / 2);



function binarySearch(arr, val){
    //lets first declare our left and right values 
    let leftIdx = 0;
    let rightIdx = arr.length - 1

    while(leftIdx <= rightIdx){
    //while left idx is smaller or equal to right
    //lets calculate the middle
    let middleIndex = Math.floor((leftIdx + rightIdx) / 2);
    //lets extract the value from this middleIndex
    let middleVal = arr[middleIndex]
    
    if(val < middleVal){
      //if our sought value is smaller than the middle
      rightIdx = middleIndex - 1
    } else if(val > middleVal){
      //if our sought value is bigger than middle
      leftIdx = middleIndex + 1
    
    } else {
      return middleIndex
    }
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(binarySearch([-1,0,3,5,9,12], 9));




Thanks Alex, yes I just saw this now, all the best

@SeanWhitty if this solves your problem don't hesitate to accept the answer (the gray checkbox), thanks
